# Image for NSSegmentedControl: how to invert it when state changes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

This is probably a no-brainer, but I can't find anything out there about it, so here goes:  if I use one of the NS template images with a NSSegmentedControl, the image inverts when the the particular segment in which it resides is depressed (when the background is dark).  It does not when I provide one of my own images.  For a normal NSButton (e.g., toggle), I can provide an alternate image to use when the button is pressed, but NSSegmentedControl does not supply an alternate image, so there must be something about the image itself that allows the control to invert its appearance.  What is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

First, follow the guidelines set out by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TP6

Next, end the name of the resulting image with the word "Template" (e.g., bigViewTemplate).

works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As [maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755190/956170) said, template image will be inverted automatically. To avoid renaming and increase flexibility just use `-(void)setTemplate:` NSImage's method.